# findViewById retorna null

Tags: java, android

Estou a receber null da minha chamada findViewById, e não consigo perceber porque. O código em baixo é relativo a uma `Activity` no meu programa:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);
        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_cpc_select, frameLayout);

        TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();
        TreeNode parent = new TreeNode("MyParentNode");
        TreeNode child0 = new TreeNode("ChildNode0");
        TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode("ChildNode1");
        parent.addChildren(child0, child1);
        root.addChild(parent);

        AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(this, root);
        FrameLayout view= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.cpc_tree_view);
        view.addView(tView.getView());    
    }
```

O meu layout está definido assim:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/cpc_tree_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Para usar o método `Activity#findViewById()` tem de indicar que a Activity usa o layout onde está esse FrameLayout através de `setContentView()`.

Comment: assim funciona. obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na linha comentada do setContentView

Trocando seu codigo para:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dashboard);

        TreeNode root = TreeNode.root();
        TreeNode parent = new TreeNode("MyParentNode");
        TreeNode child0 = new TreeNode("ChildNode0");
        TreeNode child1 = new TreeNode("ChildNode1");
        parent.addChildren(child0, child1);
        root.addChild(parent);

        AndroidTreeView tView = new AndroidTreeView(this, root);
        FrameLayout view= (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.cpc_tree_view);
        view.addView(tView.getView());    
    }
```

você consegue acessar a view com o findViewById(); Obrigatóriamente, segundo a documentação, toda view que for incializada em uma activity, tem que ser criada com o setContentView.